Python export df to pdf - Adjusting Zoom in PDFKit for Dynamic HTML Table Widths Similar to Google Sheets Fit to Width
TLDR - My goal is to mimic google sheet export to pdf functionality of "scale - fit to width" in python.
I'm trying to build an automation to export various data frames to a pdf file.
each df contains a different amount of columns, some with many columns (~30-40) and some with much less.
I do this by converting the df to html using to_html() func, and then using pdfkit library.
pdfkit.from_string(df.to_html(), "table.pdf", options={'zoom': '0.3',})

However, I can't set the zoom for a specific value as different tables require different zoom values to fit in the page properly.
If you'll go to google sheets and export a table as pdf, you'll be able to choose 'scale - fit to width' which is exactly what I want to do.
I assume it's not in the html level since if I view the raw html in browser, it looks good.
How can I achieve this?
